# Bean autowire fail when running tests only

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, junit, autowired

Hopefully someone might have the answer for this problem. 
I have a autowire problem occuring when I run my tests but not else.
The exception is pretty clear as it says 'myField' is missing. The field is however inherited from a base class. I cannot find the answer to my problem anywhere so I will try my luck here.

### The exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'myService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 
    nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: myField
```

### My base class

```
public abstract class CommonStuff {
    protected String myField; // the one thats gone missing
    public abstract void setMyField(String myField);
}
```

### My service

```
@Service("myService")
public class MyService extends CommonStuff {
    @Value("${myProperty.myField}")
    public void setMyField(String myField) {
        this.myField = myField;
    }
    ...
}
```

### My controller

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;        
    public void setMyService(MyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }
    ...
}
```

### My application-context.xml

Nothing seems to be left out.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp" />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:my.properties</value>              
            <value>classpath:myother.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

### my.properties

```
myProperty.myField=some value
```

### My test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:application-context.xml" })
public class MyControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    MyController myController;

    @Mock
    MyService myService;

    @Test
    public void myServiceTest() {
        // do stuff with myService
    }
    ...
}
```

### The problem

As I mentioned the code runs fine but a spring has trouble autowiring whenever I try to run the test.

The problem is not the test but the wiring when starting the test. Somehow spring cannot find myField from the abstract CommonStuff class so it says that MyService do not have the field.

If needed I can post the full stacktrace but I think the essense of the exception is already here.

Comment: I don't think it's complaining about the myField attribute of the parent class. I think it's complaining about the myField property use in the @Value annotation. Is the property file this comes from still on the classpath during testing?

Comment: Thx. I do not think that is the solution. The tests worked yesterday and then I started the refactoring. I moved the field into a parent class. This one and other properties was working with @Value annotation earlier. To be sure I just testet setting the property inside a static declaration. I also tried adding @PropertySource("classpath:my.properties") in the test but still no sucsess.

Comment: Post the complete configuration for `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and your `.properties` files, `@Value("${myProperty.myField}")` throws the exception because `myProperty.myField` can't be resolved

Comment: Manuel Jordan, if that is the problem. How come it works when the myService declares the field? And how do you know that it is the @Value throwing exception, when it says NoSuchFieldError?

Comment: If I put myField back into the service it works. If I leave the myField in the parent and remove the @Value("${myProperty.myField}") in myService it also works. Seems there is actually might be something with the myProperty.myField not being found. I have added the configuration above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up and moved the myField back into the service and skipped the setMyField.
This is how it is now.

### Base class

```
public abstract class CommonStuff {    
    public abstract String getMyField();
    public void doCommonStuff() {
        // use getMyField() 
    }
}
```

### My service

```
@Service("myService")
public class MyService extends CommonStuff {
    @Value("${myProperty.myField}")
    private String myField;

    @Override
    public String getMyField() {
        return myField;
    }
    ...
}
```

This solves what I wanted since I now have access to myField from CommonStuff.